# memory error size

Tags: c#, memory

I try to stream a file. I use a tab of byte.

```
byte[] byteBuffer=new byte[iSize];
```

with `iSize` value 1,459,126,243 and `GC.GetTotalMemory` at 2,489,816. I have 16 G of ram on my computer. What is the problem?

Comment: Well - what *is* the problem? You're not telling us how and where things go wrong.

Comment: `What is the problem?` Good question. What is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you compiling under x86 or x64? Unless youre runnibg under x64 you wont get the benefit of the 16gb of memory...